# Statement that calls a constructor, and does nothing with it - why does it not compile?

Tags: c++, parsing, constructor, functor

Can we have a statement that calls a constructor, and does nothing with it?

Basically, am overloading the constructor, and using the constructors without assigning it to a variable, as we would usually.
(Normally we wouldn't do this, but I could see this arising when using functors, possibly.)

Any ideas?.... (I have declared the copy constructor as private, just to make sure that this was not the cause of the problem.)

```
class myClass
{
    public:
        myClass (int n, int x) { }
        myClass (int n ) { }
    private:
        myClass (const myClass & t){}  // copy constructor is private..... 
};

int main()
{
    int r = 5;
    myClass A( r );     // OK (as per usual)
    myClass ( r, r );   // OK
    myClass ( 5 );      // OK
    myClass ( r );      // not OK : error C2371: 'r' : redefinition; different basic types

    // myClass B = myClass ( r ); // this would not work as copy constructor
                                  // has been declared as private
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is **illegal in C++**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to say `(myClass(r));`, with the extra parentheses, due to the parsing rules of C++.

(What you said is a declaration of a new variable of name `r`, which already exists. Note that you can also say `int(r);` to declare `r`.)

Comment: Thank you. The parentheses do work. But why is it that parentheses that include a whole statement are actually changing the behaviour of the statement itself? (Links to external websites would be welcome, i couldnt find it...) many thanks!!

Comment: @alexandreC: Just read up how the C++ grammar works. The first is a declaration statement, the second is an expression. There's nothing deep to it, it's just grammar.

Comment: @Karrek SB once again, thank you. I read in the standard about the ambiguity, and the specified disambiguation rules: "myClass( r )" is ambiguous, and the standard says that in such a case it should be interpreted as a declaration, not as a function call (just as you mentioned). Why then is it that the round brackets are going to change this? where in the standard does it say that "piece_of_code;" can - and will - be different from "(piece_of_code);", as you just demonstrated? once again, thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @alexandreC: There can't be a declaration that's entirely enclosed in round parentheses, so that makes it unambiguously into an *expression*.

Comment: @Kerrek SB  yes, makes sense - but where is this specified in the standard? I couldn't find this specification there, ... where in the standard can I find a paragraph where this is explicit? (sorry for the trouble :S)

Answer (score 0):

The `myClass (r);` line is actually interpreted as a definition of the `r` variable of type `myClass` (`myClass r;`), which is already defined as `int`.